# Axis client jar is was 6.1 shared app

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1, websphere-portal

I've created an axis client for a web service.  I exported as a jar and included in in the shared/app folder so that it is available to all portlet apps to use.  The problem is that when my portlet projects try to init the client I get the following exception:

```
    ERROR [org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'portalStatisticsTransactionDelegateProxy' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.uig.portal.ws.statistics.service.PortalStatisticsTransactionDelegateProxy]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient (initialization failure)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:653)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:370)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:293)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:162)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:673)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:335)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:551)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1138)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:569)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:817)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:921)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2124)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.uig.portal.ws.statistics.service.PortalStatisticsTransactionDelegateProxy]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient (initialization failure)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)
    at com.uig.portal.ws.statistics.service.PortalStatisticsTransactionServiceLocator.<init>(PortalStatisticsTransactionServiceLocator.java:12)
    at com.uig.portal.ws.statistics.service.PortalStatisticsTransactionDelegateProxy._initPortalStatisticsTransactionDelegateProxy(PortalStatisticsTransactionDelegateProxy.java:18)
    at com.uig.portal.ws.statistics.service.PortalStatisticsTransactionDelegateProxy.<init>(PortalStatisticsTransactionDelegateProxy.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 32 more
```

Any ideas?  I tried referencing the axis jars from my portlet project, but that didn't work.

Comment: The "(initialization failure)" indicates that the JVM has marked the class as bad because class initialization failed.  There should be an earlier error in the logs somewhere that shows an "at ...AxisClient.<client>" stack frame, and that's the cause of this exception.  What does that exception say?

Comment: I added the full stack trace.  Any ideas?

Comment: No, that's the full stack trace of the NoClassDefFoundError.  There should be another error (somewhere) that shows a stack trace that includes "at ...AxisClient.<clinit>" (sorry, my previous comment erroneously said "client" rather than "clinit").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your client jar interferes with standard websphere libraries. It leads to a situation where two different versions of the same class exist on the server classloader hierarchy. Your application classs loader probably picks the wrong version.

I would suggest to remove the jar from shared/app and configure a shared library instead. Then you associate the shared library with your application. You can find more details in [was infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tcws_sharedlib.html).